# Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Estava convertendo para apk normalmente mas parou e começou a dar esse error procurei ja adicionei o caminho c:\windows\system32 ao path e ainda não foi, ja reinstalei e tudo mais e ainda acusa o mesmo problema, toda vez que dou o comando: ionic cordova run android.

```
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\IONIC\Backup\06-12-18\App\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\pc\Downloads\IONIC\Backup\06-12-18\App\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m""
Command finished with error code ENOENT: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\IONIC\Backup\06-12-18\App\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\pc\Downloads\IONIC\Backup\06-12-18\App\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m"
cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\pc\Downloads\IONIC\Backup\06-12-18\App\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como estão configuradas suas variáveis de ambiente ? Poderia nos fornecer um print ?

Comment: Sim posso, colocarei acima.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` está com  um `;` antes e tem várias outras variáveis na mesma linha que deveriam estar divididas, como `%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tolls`. Acredito que a cada `;` deveria ser uma variável diferente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te explicar em uma forma resumida e de fácil entendimento :

Em variáveis do sistema, pasta Path você precisar ter :

1. Caminho do Node/js
2. Caminho do sdk/tools
3. Caminho do Gradle

Ainda em variáveis do sistema, você precisar criar algumas variáveis, desse mesmo modo:

4. JAVA_HOME : o caminho do seu jdk
5. ANDROID_HOME : o caminho do sdK
6. GRADLE_HOME : o caminho do Gradle

   Tente isso.

Comment: Já tenho tudo instalado, mas vou verificar novamente tudo, talvez baixar um projeto só para testar.

Comment: Uma dica que te dou : faz um projeto em branco, após isso, tente fazer o build. Se tudo der certo, é sinal de que o erro não é nas variáveis de ambiente.

Comment: Vlw ai man mas não funcionou mais tarde irei tentar em outro computador vlw pela ajuda.